# lambda expressions not working in netbeans jdk 1.8 project

Tags: java, netbeans, lambda, java-8

Even though I changed my netbeans project's jdk to 1.8, it still gives the following error

```
lambda expressions not expected here

lambda expressions are not supported in-source 1.7
(use source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

Any help is so much appreciated

Comment: Is this a Maven project? It must be specified in your project's pom.xml.

Comment: In the project properties, did you only set Libraries->Java Platform or did you also set Source->Source/Binary Format?

Comment: thanks a lot @Thomas, I didn't set the later one. Now It work's perfect.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the project properties for the target version. Java 8 allows you to build for Java 7 execution, and that setting is still there from when you used Java 7. Right-click on the Project in the "Projects" window and select "Properties", then "Sources" in that dialog. On the right you will see "Source/Binary Format". Change that to "1.8", then click "OK".